# Java-lib for XML tree visualization

Tags: java, xml, visualization

How to visualize XML from Java?

Comment: eclipse's xml tree view is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache Pivot Project](http://pivot.apache.org/demos/xml-viewer.html) contains a XML Viewer. If you rely on a specific library you should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html