# Java: visual xml editor and tree visualizer swing component I can embed into my application?

Tags: java, xml, swing, editor, tree

Is there a open source or commercial component for a visual xml tree editor? It should parse an xml  file and allow the user to easily edit nodes, attributes etc.

Basically, user also needs to be able to add nodes in real time.

Comment: I did an example for viewing xml files in jtree, you can modify it in order to allow edition:http://halexv.blogspot.mx/2015/07/simple-java-xml-viewer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can write one by your self. Just parse the file and you can use a JTreeTable (swingx) to render it and manipulate it dynamically.
You can see this post:
[java-lib for xml tree visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350548/java-lib-for-xml-tree-visualization)
The answer by Kumar has an example on how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse editor have a pretty good xml editor. It can show xml in source and in tree-like view.
http://www.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the excellent article for generating a tree view structure based on the given xml file on the fly.

http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3731356/Displaying-XML-in-a-Swing-JTree.htm

once the tree structure is generated you have to write your own logic to edit , add nodes.

Comment: Sure, the wheel could be reinvented but there HAS to be something already written and working already out there...

Comment: Dead link, update?

Comment: Updated Link: https://www.developer.com/java/displaying-xml-in-a-swing-jtree/